# Getting scrollviewer from Collapsed ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm struggeling to get the ScrollViewer from my Collapsed ListBox.
It is going to be visible and I've tried:

-After Loaded event:

```
        documentListBox.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var scroller = documentListBox.Template.FindName("Scroller", documentListBox);
            var scroller1 = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(documentListBox);
            var scroller2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(documentListBox);
            var scroller3 = Extensions.GetDescendantByType(documentListBox, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
            var scroller4 = documentListBox.Template.FindName("ScrollViewer", documentListBox) as ScrollViewer;
        }


      ----------------Extensions.GetDescendantByType:----------------
   public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (element.GetType() == type)
        {
            return element;
        }
        Visual foundElement = null;
        if (element is FrameworkElement)
        {
            (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
            if (foundElement != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundElement;
    }
```

-After IsVisibleChanged:

```
    documentListBox.IsVisibleChanged+=VisibilityChanged

    VisibilityChanged(){
            var scroller = Extensions.GetDescendantByType(documentListBox, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
            var scroller1 = documentListBox.Template.FindName("ScrollViewer", documentListBox) as ScrollViewer;
            var scroller2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(documentListBox);
            var scroller3 = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(documentListBox);
     }
```

Also tried to override ListBox and Add this Property in both cases:

```
       public ScrollViewer Scroller
    {
        get
        {
            return GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
        }
    }
```

All of these either gave me something else or `null`.
Any Idea of what to call? Or where I could access it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it by adding a new Template:

```
        <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
```

And then override OnRender in my Codebehind:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    base.OnRender(dc);
    var scrollviewer = (documentListView.Template.FindName("Scroller", documentListView)) as ScrollViewer;
```

Also had to change the visibility settings:

```
Visibility="{Binding ViewIsVisible, Converter={Panels:BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}"
```

Setting this to false in my VM made the view collapse, after it beeing rendered.

The reason for this is that `ListBox/ListView` doesn't render their `Template` before beeing visible (more efficient).